# Saving data to a model with association hasMany does not work

Tags: extjs

I want to keep the information about posts to the user. Save turns. But at the output of the data on the posts no longer exists.

Why are not posts stored?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22mp

```
    Ext.define('Post', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        fields: [{
            name: 'title',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    });

    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        fields: [{
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }],

        hasMany: 'Post'
    });

    var user = Ext.create('User', {
        name: "user1"
    });


    user.posts().add({
        title: 'Post 10'
    });

    user.posts().sync();

    console.log(user.getData()); // There are no posts!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 
`user.getData({associated:true});` to get the associated data for more information please see the documentation.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.data.Model.html#method-getData

Comment: Thanks for the answer!